# Simple Question about Wronskian for Testing Functional Dependence

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm confused about how my text has come about the following solution:

Problem asks to verify if the provided solution functions are linearly independent on interval $ (- \infty, \infty) $

$$
f_{1}(x)=x, \quad f_{2}(x)=x^{2}, \quad f_{3}(x)=4 x-3 x^{2}
$$

I'm perfectly able to set up the Wronskian and find the determinant according to:
$$
W\left(f_{1}, f_{2}, \ldots, f_{n}\right)=\left|\begin{array}{cccc}f_{1} & f_{2} & \dots & f_{n} \\ f_{1} & f_{2}^{\prime} & \dots & f_{n}^{\prime} \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ f_{1}^{(n-1)} & f_{2}^{(n-1)} & \dots & f_{n}^{(n-1)}\end{array}\right|
$$

Doing so with the above functions, I get the correct answer of Zero: The matrix vanishes and we have linearly dependent functions. But this is the solution provided by the text:
$$
\text { since }(-4) x+(3) x^{2}+(1)\left(4 x-3 x^{2}\right)=0 \text { the set of functions is linearly dependent. }
$$
This calculation doesn't make sense to me. I don't see how to get (-4), (3) and (1) assuming we're expanding across first row.

Comment: They are proving linear dependence by inspection. Using Wronskian  is not the  only way to prove linear dependence.

Comment: I think I just saw that. It doesn't calculate but shows the interdependence I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly by looking at the terms of the third function you can see that
$$
f_3(x)=4f_1(x)-3f_2(x).
$$
This form of having one vector represented as linear combination of other vectors is the original definition of linear dependence, $f_3$ depends linearly on $f_1,f_2$. Or put another way, there is a non-trivial linear combination of $f_1,f_2,f_3$ resulting in the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're given the problem

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $v,w\in V$. Determine whether the set consisting of the vectors $v$, $w$ and $4v-3w$ is linearly independent

you probably answer immediately a loud *no*, because no three-element set in the subspace generated by two vectors can be linearly independent.

You're given the *same* problem, just with specific vectors in a specific vector space.